# Tensorflow Dataset - ArrowInvalid: Called Open() on an uninitialized FileSource

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a tensorflow dataset that loads and preprocesses Parquet files, but when I try to map my preprocess function I get the below error:

```
StagingError: in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-22-245243856ef3>", line 2, in preprocess_data  *
        data = load_relevant_data_subset(path)
    File "<ipython-input-20-0f01af668bc5>", line 3, in load_relevant_data_subset  *
        data = pd.read_parquet(pq_path, columns=data_columns)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 493, in read_parquet  **
        return impl.read(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/parquet.py", line 240, in read
        result = self.api.parquet.read_table(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 2780, in read_table
        dataset = _ParquetDatasetV2(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyarrow/parquet/__init__.py", line 2368, in __init__
        [fragment], schema=schema or fragment.physical_schema,
    File "pyarrow/_dataset.pyx", line 898, in pyarrow._dataset.Fragment.physical_schema.__get__
        
    File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 144, in pyarrow.lib.pyarrow_internal_check_status
        
    File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
        

    ArrowInvalid: Called Open() on an uninitialized FileSource
```

This is the preprocess function:

```
def preprocess_data(path, label):
    data = load_relevant_data_subset(path)
    data = tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(data), tf.reduce_mean(tf.where(tf.math.is_nan(data), tf.zeros_like(data), data)), data)
    target_size = (80, 543)
    data = tf.image.resize(data, target_size, method='bilinear')
    return data, label
```

Then I create a list of paths and the train_dataset:

```
file_paths = [os.path.join(root_path, p) for p in train['path'].tolist()]
labels = train['label'].tolist()
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_paths, labels))
```

Then try to map it:

```
train_dataset=train_dataset.map(preprocess_data,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

And it returns the error. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to wrap your preprocessing function into `tf.numpy_function`, something like this:

```
def tf_preprocess_data(path, label):
    return tf.numpy_function(preprocess_data, inp=[data, label], Tout=(tf.float32, tf.int32))
```

Also, we have to convert the `path` from bytes to a string, something like this:

```
def preprocess_data(path, label):
    path = path.decode("utf-8")
    data = pd.read_parquet(path)
    ...
```